# sending mail through cakephp3 appends via cp-in-12.webhostbox.net

Tags: email, cakephp

i am facing a problem when i send email using cakephp3 on my hosting. Emails are being sent but when i view the recieved email in browser i see this along with the email address from i'm sending the email 
From: no-reply@mail.com  via cp-in-12.webhostbox.net 
However when i check mail in phone's gmail client 'via cp-in-12.webhostbox.net' does not shows up.
Here is my code
    `$email = new Email('default');
    $email->from(['no-reply@mail.com' => 'no-reply@mail.com'])
            ->to('mymail@gmail.com')
            ->subject('Test Mail')
            ->send('Thank You! for purchase! its a test mail');
        }`
Please help.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Google appends the "via mail.domain.com" when the sending domain does not have any sort of SPF records on it. It's to notify users that the email may not have originated from the "From" email address' domain, but since you don't have any restrictions (set by SPF), Google can't tell if you're a bad guy, or just haven't set up your records yet. You're going to want to either setup some SPF and DKIM records (check with your webhost on how to do that), and that should eliminate those messages. The reason it doesn't appear on iPhone is because that platform does not have that feature.

Comment: i went to cpanel -> Email ->Authentication and there DKIM and SPF both are enabled. I tried sending the email from webmail and it worked but when am doing this with code am getting that via text appended. Do you have any idea what am doing wrong ?

Comment: There's a possibility that you need to use the details for your webmail to setup an SMTP server. Usually cPanel has an option for configuring a mail client. If you select manual when doing that, it should tell you details which you can then use in your application's SMTP configuration.

Comment: EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Mail',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 25,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'no-reply@mail.com',
            'password' => '******',
            'client' => null,
            'tls' => null,
            'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        ],
    ],

This is my code in app/config.php is there anything wrong with this ?

Comment: As long as the data inside "host", "port", "username", and "password" are correct according to your mail client! I've not worked with cakePHP much, but there may be a possibility that you have to specifically tell cakePHP to transport mail via SMTP rather than through the inbuilt mail() function.

Comment: Thank You so much for your help . I will do some more search regarding this